# What kind of hash is this?

Tags: hash

If someone can help me, can you help me identify this hash?

51a5a55a2a173a177a30a167a70a145a105a94a121a112a10a87

Comment: I bet you know more of the hash than we do. Where did you get that hash from? Hey. I see a pattern

Comment: you've made a bit of a hash of this question

Comment: Encrypted version of a password for something. Need the password itself.

Comment: It's the location of Jimmy Hoffa's corpse.

Comment: @Hy Diep: an encryption is NOT a hash!  Hashes are one way....

Comment: I have to wonder what the heck system would encode a hash value this way instead of using base64?

Comment: @Hy Diep on a serious note, the whole point of **securing** a password by hashing it is that it is irreversible, you cannot get the password back, you could only do dictionary attack which would take large amounts of time depending on what hash algorithm was used.

Comment: @Hy Diep: I don't think much more can be deduced from this without more details, e.g., what kind of system it came from, what program generated it, or such.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like some data separated by "a".
The parts, after split by `a`:

```
51
5
55
2
173
177
30
167
70
145
105
94
121
112
10
87
```

It's not ASCII. Another operation must have been applied to it.

Comment: There are 16 numbers ranging from 2 to 177. If we assume each is an octet, that makes it 128 bits.

Comment: i keep thinking of it as x,y pos , maybe theres something to that ...

Comment: It's not an octet, there is a `87`.

Comment: Translating to hex, it's 33053702adb11ea74691695e79700a57. Which is just as opaque as before, just in a more familiar format.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It's not a simple XOR operation I think, using frequency analysis.

Comment: look at my answer.... the second one...

Comment: @Vamana: those 128 bits may be MD5, but the usual MD5 reverse lookup sites didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

That thing is 52 hexadecimal digits, i.e. 26 bytes, i.e. 208 bits. I've never seen "standard" hashes of 208 bits, in general they are in powers of 2. It may as well be anything, probably it is just "normal" binary data.

---

***Edit*** actually, as @Vamana noticed, it probably isn't hexadecimal as it may have looked at first glance, since the only non-numerical digit that appears is *a*, which instead is probably a separator of some kind.

---

***Edit again*** are you sure that you didn't miss some leading zero? IMO those "A" started as 0A characters, which are newlines.

Comment: I don't think it's hexadecimal. The only letter that appears is 'a', and it appears 15 times, more than any other character. All the digits 0-9 are present, but the distribution appears nonrandom.

Comment: @Vamana: true, I was now looking at it in a hex editor and I see  that there are some strong recurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this has no connection at all, but it is interesting that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491231/what-kind-of-hash-is-this) somebody asked about a "hash" that is a base64 encoded version of a 26 byte hash. So perhaps there is some exotic 26 byte hash? Or perhaps some kind of 26 byte long data/ID?

Answer (score 0):

it is
QUR1w0wEYA!!
hexxed, joined by a (in wierd positions)...

http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/ pwns

did i kill the fun ? :( sorry

Comment: Please do not add multiple answers, edit your old one instead. How did you get this?

Comment: split by 'a', paste into hex box on http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/ , press decode. so this wasnt a joke? .o0

Comment: hmm i think im wr0ng anyway ;P it just looked like sensible data